# Angular unit test spyOn class from node_modules

Tags: node.js, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create a spy to make sure function was called from node_modules class
For example in obs.d.ts:

```
export declare module Obs {
   
    class MyService {
    
         
        func(params: Object): Promise<void>;
```

so I would like to spy on func()

In my test I am currently trying:

```
import { Obs } from 'obs';


describe('CurrentService', () => {

 let test: Obs.MyService;

let spy;

 beforeEach(() => {

//test.func();  //this works

spy = spyOn(test, 'func');   // spy does not

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.get(CurrentService);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The func method should be called in the CurrentService's constructor.

gets error : "Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for func()"

Problem is not recognizing func method in spy, even though test.func() works (see commented out part of code).

Not sure if this is an import issue. I believe the spy will work if you actually create the class (i.e. test = new Obs.MyService() but that will be useless because that new class instance is not being touched in CurrentService.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't you inject obs in your CurrentService? Can't you just mock it and then spy on it.. instead of trying to call the real thing.

Comment: no Obs is imported from a node module

Comment: it's being called in a function called in the constructor

Comment: just need to make sure it was called, can't access function in service since no way to set up spy before construction and this function starts the whole application so can't just create new service easily

Answer (score 0):

Try this although this may not work either:

```
import * as ObsContainer from 'obs';


describe('CurrentService', () => {

let spy;

 beforeEach(() => {

//test.func();  //this works

spy = spyOn(ObsContainer.MyService, 'func');

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.get(CurrentService);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: thanks, I had attempted that already, not working here, not sure why